# typeahead not working with lower version of ui bootstrap

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

Here is the plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/fTdu3CymMXeo4Dfpu6Gm?p=preview)  if you changed the version of

`<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.4.0.js"></script>` to

`ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js`, it works fine but i need to make the typeahead in v0.4.0. 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I have edited your plunkr and here is working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Boi9KYdmwTn8fSL7nBUl?p=preview)

The only change that I have made is changed the version of angular js you are using.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js"></script>
```

If you want to use ui-bootstrap-0.4.0 than you have to use older version of angular because for newer version of angular it seems that its not compatible properly.

Hope this will help you. Thanks.

Comment: 0.4.0 is almost 1-year old, time to upgrade :-) https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#040-2013-06-24